# How can I use "operator X()" defined in class?

Tags: c++, operators

I'm relatively new to C++, and this declaration has me confused:

Service.h:

```
class ServiceHandle {
  public:
    ServiceHandle(SC_HANDLE h) : handle(h) {}
    ...
    operator SC_HANDLE() const {return handle;}
  protected:
    SC_HANDLE handle;
};
```

I've created a `ServiceHandle` object through other means than the constructor listed here. I'd like to get the actual `SC_HANDLE` to pass to [`ChangeServiceConfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), how do I get at it? I'm assuming it's something to do with the operator, but I can't work out how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use the object of type `ServiceHandle` in the expression tht expects `SC_HANDLE`. The *operator* you're talking about is the casting operator to `SC_HANDLE`. This operator is "used" automatically.

Answer (score 0):

That is a casting operator. This would call it:

```
ServiceHandle s(some handle);
SC_HANDLE h = (SC_HANDLE)s;
```

Comment: `SC_HANDLE h = s;` will suffice. Avoid C-style casts like fire.

Comment: Agreed. Writing a C-style cast did make me feel a little bit sick.